# Install network adaptor without having access of internet in lubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu

I accidentally removed all(wifi, ethernet and usb) network adaptors from my lubuntu machine. I am not able to connect my laptop to internet via any means.

I have been trying to download adaptor files using my phone and installing them in laptop but no luck so far as i dont know which chipset should be appropriate for my version.

Can anyone help me please?

(Sorry for not mentioning what i did so far just because of im typing in phone)

Comment: Any details on how you accidentally removed them?

Comment: I would look in your `/var/log/apt/history.log`  (or your command `history` etc) to see what you removed; and just re-install it. If you don't `apt-get autoclean` very often & wish some luck, some of the .debs may still be on your machine; but if not I'd just download them elsewhere (another machine), copy to usb & install that way...  To view your hardware use `sudo lshw -C network` (copying to thumb-drive and uploading on a borrowed system rather than a phone if you can)

Comment: I was using orphaner for removing unused softwares. I was not aware that it is suggesting system programs. So i removed all of them which was being suggested by it

Comment: Is there any way in orpahner to see the removed files?

Comment: `orphaner` is a front-end for `deborphan` which then calls `apt-get` to do any removal; so the logs are in `/var/log/apt/history.log` as already stated.

Comment: Thanks ... Im trying that way.. i'll update if it works.. as it seems many dependancy files out there..

Comment: I tried to get logs and downloading all removed files which were around 150+ files. I tried few of them to install but they have interdependencies.. so i dont think this will help me